# Specify only one index with fluent api

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, ef-fluent-api

Is there a way to only specify one index when overriding the `OnModelCreating` function in our context folder?

I added:

```
builder.Entity<ApplicationUser>()
    .HasIndex(e => e.Id);
```

Which does add that as an index, but it looks like a few other properties have been made an index as well.

Is there a way to make it the only index?

The reason why I want to specify one index is:
my migration file theres a bunch of dropForeignKeys, RenameTable, CreateIndex for things that i haven't touched. It happens to try to drop an index that Isn't even in my table which causes my migration to fail. Which is why I want to only specify one index

Context File:
`

```
public class MyContext : IdentityDbContext
    {
        public MyContext(DbContextOptions<MyContext> options) : base(options)
        { }

        // Snippet, I only added this InboxNotification so I expected to only see a create and corresponding drop table
        public virtual DbSet<InboxNotification> InboxNotifications { get; set; }

        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {

        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
        {
            base.OnModelCreating(builder);

            builder.Entity<ApplicationRole>()
                .HasMany(e => e.Claims)
                .WithOne()
                .HasForeignKey(e => e.RoleId)
                .IsRequired()
                .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);

            builder.Entity<ApplicationRole>()
                .HasMany(e => e.Users)
                .WithOne()
                .HasForeignKey(e => e.RoleId)
                .IsRequired()
                .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);

            builder.Entity<ApplicationUser>()
                .HasMany(e => e.Claims)
                .WithOne()
                .HasForeignKey(e => e.UserId)
                .IsRequired()
                .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);

            builder.Entity<ApplicationUser>()
                .HasMany(e => e.Logins)
                .WithOne()
                .HasForeignKey(e => e.UserId)
                .IsRequired()
                .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);

            builder.Entity<ApplicationUser>()
                .HasMany(e => e.Roles)
                .WithOne()
                .HasForeignKey(e => e.UserId)
                .IsRequired()
                .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);

            // // Maps the .NET types to our db
            // builder.Entity<IdentityUser>().ToTable("AspNetUsers")
            //     .HasKey(x => x.Id);

            // builder.Entity<IdentityRole>().ToTable("AspNetRoles")
            //     .HasKey(x => x.Id);

            builder.Entity<IdentityUserRole<string>>().ToTable("AspNetUserRoles")
                .HasKey(x => new { x.UserId, x.RoleId });

            builder.Entity<IdentityUserClaim<string>>().ToTable("AspNetUserClaims")
                .HasKey(x => x.Id);

            builder.Entity<IdentityUserLogin<string>>().ToTable("AspNetUserLogins")
                .HasKey(x => new { x.UserId, x.ProviderKey });

            builder.Entity<IdentityUserToken<string>>().ToTable("AspNetUserTokens")
                .HasKey(x => new { x.UserId, x.LoginProvider, x.Name });

            builder.Entity<IdentityRoleClaim<string>>().ToTable("AspNetRoleClaims")
                .HasKey(x => x.Id);

            builder.Entity<ApplicationUserToken>().ToTable("UserTokens")
            .HasKey(x => x.Id);

            builder.Entity<Team>()
                .HasIndex(t => new
                {
                    t.Name,
                    t.LeagueId
                })
                .HasName("Team_Name")
                .IsUnique();

            builder.Entity<Club>()
                .HasIndex(c => c.Name)
                .IsUnique();

            builder.Entity<TeamMatch>()
                .HasIndex(tm => new
                {
                    tm.Name,
                    tm.TeamId
                })
                .IsUnique();
            builder.Entity<TeamMatch>()
                .HasIndex(tm => new
                {
                    tm.Slug,
                    tm.TeamId
                })
                .IsUnique();
            builder.Entity<Practice>()
                .HasIndex(p => new { p.Name, p.TeamId })
                .IsUnique();
            builder.Entity<Practice>()
                .HasIndex(p => new { p.Slug, p.TeamId })
                .IsUnique();


            builder.Entity<SocialPlayFriend>()
              .HasKey(t => new { t.PlayerId, t.SocialPlayPreferenceId });

            builder.Entity<SocialPlayFriend>()
              .HasOne(f => f.Preference)
              .WithMany(spp => spp.Friends)
              .HasForeignKey(f => f.SocialPlayPreferenceId);

            builder.Entity<SocialPlayFriend>()
              .HasOne(f => f.Friend)
              .WithMany(p => p.Friends)
              .HasForeignKey(f => f.PlayerId);

            builder.Entity<SocialPlayClub>()
              .HasKey(c => new { c.SocialPlayPreferenceId, c.ClubId });

            builder.Entity<SocialPlayClub>()
              .HasOne(f => f.Preference)
              .WithMany(spp => spp.Clubs)
              .HasForeignKey(f => f.SocialPlayPreferenceId);

            builder.Entity<SocialPlayClub>()
              .HasOne(f => f.Club)
              .WithMany(c => c.SocialPlayers)
              .HasForeignKey(f => f.ClubId);

        }
    }
```

`

Migration File:
`

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace MyAPI.Migrations
{
    public partial class InboxNotification : Migration
    {
        protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
        {
            migrationBuilder.DropForeignKey(
                name: "FK_ApplicationUserToken_AspNetUsers_UserId",
                table: "ApplicationUserToken");

            migrationBuilder.DropIndex(
                name: "Team_Name",
                table: "Teams");

            migrationBuilder.DropIndex(
                name: "IX_TeamMatches_Name_TeamId",
                table: "TeamMatches");

            migrationBuilder.DropIndex(
                name: "IX_TeamMatches_Slug_TeamId",
                table: "TeamMatches");

            migrationBuilder.DropIndex(
                name: "IX_Practices_Name_TeamId",
                table: "Practices");

            migrationBuilder.DropIndex(
                name: "IX_Practices_Slug_TeamId",
                table: "Practices");

            migrationBuilder.DropIndex(
                name: "IX_Players_UserId",
                table: "Players");

            migrationBuilder.DropIndex(
                name: "IX_Clubs_Name",
                table: "Clubs");

            migrationBuilder.DropIndex(
                name: "UserNameIndex",
                table: "AspNetUsers");

            migrationBuilder.DropPrimaryKey(
                name: "PK_ApplicationUserToken",
                table: "ApplicationUserToken");

            migrationBuilder.DropIndex(
                name: "RoleNameIndex",
                table: "AspNetRoles");

            migrationBuilder.RenameTable(
                name: "ApplicationUserToken",
                newName: "UserTokens");

            migrationBuilder.RenameIndex(
                name: "IX_ApplicationUserToken_UserId",
                table: "UserTokens",
                newName: "IX_UserTokens_UserId");

            migrationBuilder.AddColumn<string>(
                name: "Discriminator",
                table: "AspNetRoles",
                type: "nvarchar(max)",
                nullable: false,
                defaultValue: "");

            migrationBuilder.AddPrimaryKey(
                name: "PK_UserTokens",
                table: "UserTokens",
                column: "Id");

            migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
                name: "InboxNotifications",
                columns: table => new
                {
                    Id = table.Column<string>(type: "nvarchar(450)", nullable: false),
                    Created = table.Column<DateTime>(type: "datetime2", nullable: false),
                    CreatedBy = table.Column<string>(type: "nvarchar(max)", nullable: true),
                    DataId = table.Column<string>(type: "nvarchar(max)", nullable: true),
                    EventIdent = table.Column<string>(type: "nvarchar(max)", nullable: true),
                    Message = table.Column<string>(type: "nvarchar(max)", nullable: true),
                    Status = table.Column<int>(type: "int", nullable: false),
                    TeamIdent = table.Column<string>(type: "nvarchar(max)", nullable: true),
                    Title = table.Column<string>(type: "nvarchar(max)", nullable: true),
                    Type = table.Column<int>(type: "int", nullable: false),
                    UserId = table.Column<string>(type: "nvarchar(max)", nullable: true)
                },
                constraints: table =>
                {
                    table.PrimaryKey("PK_InboxNotifications", x => x.Id);
                });

            migrationBuilder.CreateIndex(
                name: "Team_Name",
                table: "Teams",
                columns: new[] { "Name", "LeagueId" },
                unique: true,
                filter: "[Name] IS NOT NULL AND [LeagueId] IS NOT NULL");

            migrationBuilder.CreateIndex(
                name: "IX_TeamMatches_Name_TeamId",
                table: "TeamMatches",
                columns: new[] { "Name", "TeamId" },
                unique: true,
                filter: "[Name] IS NOT NULL AND [TeamId] IS NOT NULL");

            migrationBuilder.CreateIndex(
                name: "IX_TeamMatches_Slug_TeamId",
                table: "TeamMatches",
                columns: new[] { "Slug", "TeamId" },
                unique: true,
                filter: "[Slug] IS NOT NULL AND [TeamId] IS NOT NULL");

            migrationBuilder.CreateIndex(
                name: "IX_Practices_Name_TeamId",
                table: "Practices",
                columns: new[] { "Name", "TeamId" },
                unique: true,
                filter: "[Name] IS NOT NULL AND [TeamId] IS NOT NULL");

            migrationBuilder.CreateIndex(
                name: "IX_Practices_Slug_TeamId",
                table: "Practices",
                columns: new[] { "Slug", "TeamId" },
                unique: true,
                filter: "[Slug] IS NOT NULL AND [TeamId] IS NOT NULL");

            migrationBuilder.CreateIndex(
                name: "IX_Players_UserId",
                table: "Players",
                column: "UserId",
                unique: true,
                filter: "[UserId] IS NOT NULL");

            migrationBuilder.CreateIndex(
                name: "IX_Clubs_Name",
                table: "Clubs",
                column: "Name",
                unique: true,
                filter: "[Name] IS NOT NULL");

            migrationBuilder.CreateIndex(
                name: "UserNameIndex",
                table: "AspNetUsers",
                column: "NormalizedUserName",
                unique: true,
                filter: "[NormalizedUserName] IS NOT NULL");

            migrationBuilder.CreateIndex(
                name: "RoleNameIndex",
                table: "AspNetRoles",
                column: "NormalizedName",
                unique: true,
                filter: "[NormalizedName] IS NOT NULL");

            migrationBuilder.AddForeignKey(
                name: "FK_AspNetUserTokens_AspNetUsers_UserId",
                table: "AspNetUserTokens",
                column: "UserId",
                principalTable: "AspNetUsers",
                principalColumn: "Id",
                onDelete: ReferentialAction.Cascade);

            migrationBuilder.AddForeignKey(
                name: "FK_UserTokens_AspNetUsers_UserId",
                table: "UserTokens",
                column: "UserId",
                principalTable: "AspNetUsers",
                principalColumn: "Id",
                onDelete: ReferentialAction.Restrict);
        }

        protected override void Down(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
        {
            migrationBuilder.DropForeignKey(
                name: "FK_AspNetUserTokens_AspNetUsers_UserId",
                table: "AspNetUserTokens");

            migrationBuilder.DropForeignKey(
                name: "FK_UserTokens_AspNetUsers_UserId",
                table: "UserTokens");

            migrationBuilder.DropTable(
                name: "InboxNotifications");

            migrationBuilder.DropPrimaryKey(
                name: "PK_UserTokens",
                table: "UserTokens");

            migrationBuilder.DropIndex(
                name: "Team_Name",
                table: "Teams");

            migrationBuilder.DropIndex(
                name: "IX_TeamMatches_Name_TeamId",
                table: "TeamMatches");

            migrationBuilder.DropIndex(
                name: "IX_TeamMatches_Slug_TeamId",
                table: "TeamMatches");

            migrationBuilder.DropIndex(
                name: "IX_Practices_Name_TeamId",
                table: "Practices");

            migrationBuilder.DropIndex(
                name: "IX_Practices_Slug_TeamId",
                table: "Practices");

            migrationBuilder.DropIndex(
                name: "IX_Players_UserId",
                table: "Players");

            migrationBuilder.DropIndex(
                name: "IX_Clubs_Name",
                table: "Clubs");

            migrationBuilder.DropIndex(
                name: "UserNameIndex",
                table: "AspNetUsers");

            migrationBuilder.DropIndex(
                name: "RoleNameIndex",
                table: "AspNetRoles");

            migrationBuilder.DropColumn(
                name: "Discriminator",
                table: "AspNetRoles");

            migrationBuilder.RenameTable(
                name: "UserTokens",
                newName: "ApplicationUserToken");

            migrationBuilder.RenameIndex(
                name: "IX_UserTokens_UserId",
                table: "ApplicationUserToken",
                newName: "IX_ApplicationUserToken_UserId");

            migrationBuilder.AddPrimaryKey(
                name: "PK_ApplicationUserToken",
                table: "ApplicationUserToken",
                column: "Id");

            migrationBuilder.CreateIndex(
                name: "Team_Name",
                table: "Teams",
                columns: new[] { "Name", "LeagueId" },
                unique: true);

            migrationBuilder.CreateIndex(
                name: "IX_TeamMatches_Name_TeamId",
                table: "TeamMatches",
                columns: new[] { "Name", "TeamId" },
                unique: true);

            migrationBuilder.CreateIndex(
                name: "IX_TeamMatches_Slug_TeamId",
                table: "TeamMatches",
                columns: new[] { "Slug", "TeamId" },
                unique: true);

            migrationBuilder.CreateIndex(
                name: "IX_Practices_Name_TeamId",
                table: "Practices",
                columns: new[] { "Name", "TeamId" },
                unique: true);

            migrationBuilder.CreateIndex(
                name: "IX_Practices_Slug_TeamId",
                table: "Practices",
                columns: new[] { "Slug", "TeamId" },
                unique: true);

            migrationBuilder.CreateIndex(
                name: "IX_Players_UserId",
                table: "Players",
                column: "UserId",
                unique: true);

            migrationBuilder.CreateIndex(
                name: "IX_Clubs_Name",
                table: "Clubs",
                column: "Name",
                unique: true);

            migrationBuilder.CreateIndex(
                name: "UserNameIndex",
                table: "AspNetUsers",
                column: "NormalizedUserName",
                unique: true);

            migrationBuilder.CreateIndex(
                name: "RoleNameIndex",
                table: "AspNetRoles",
                column: "NormalizedName",
                unique: true);

            migrationBuilder.AddForeignKey(
                name: "FK_ApplicationUserToken_AspNetUsers_UserId",
                table: "ApplicationUserToken",
                column: "UserId",
                principalTable: "AspNetUsers",
                principalColumn: "Id",
                onDelete: ReferentialAction.Restrict);
        }
    }
}
```

`

Comment: *but it looks like a few other properties have been made an index...* - what makes you say this? Your migration? Your DB table? Why do you need just the one index on there? Can you give a little more context? *(every pun intended)*

Comment: @GeoffJames lol at pun. Yeah in my migration file theres a bunch of dropForeignKeys, RenameTable, CreateIndex for things that i haven't touched. It happens to try to drop an index that Isn't even in my table which causes my migration to fail. Which is why I want to only specify one index.

Comment: Is it possible for you to add this to your question? It's quite a key bit of information as to *why* you're looking for this, specifically. I'd probably look more into why your migration is trying to drop an index not in your table. You're only going to make your life harder trying to find a solution to something that isn't directly your issue (see [the XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)), when you could have solved the original issue by looking in more detail at what's happening. Could you also post the code for your suspicious migration?

Comment: @GeoffJames Yeah I can post the code. It'd probably be the code in the context file right?

Comment: It'll be the migration `.cs` file that you referred to previously (with the drop foreign keys, table renames etc). You'll usually have a folder called `Migrations`, which contains your migrations. They're prefixed with a timestamp, so they list in chronological order, then `_MigrationName` of whatever you specified.

Comment: @GeoffJames Okay I added the two files. It's also worth noting that I recently migrated from .NET 1.1.4 over to .NET 2.0.0  These 'extra' migration properties seem to be from all previous migrations( I'm not 100% sure its true, but it seems like it).

Comment: I don't think you necessarily need *all* of your context file, to be honest. You already included the snippet in your original question. The migration  would have been enough on its own. That's a lot of migration changes to indexes in one go. I'm not sure if this is a side-effect of updating your .NET Core/EF Core, recently (I'm guessing you meant .NET Core). I don't think your solution is going to solve the original problem. I would retrace your steps and try to figure out exactly where it went wrong, and what errors you're getting as a result, that might help you fix the underlying issue.

Comment: *It happens to try to drop an index that Isn't even in my table which causes my migration to fail* - I would tackle this issue, first and foremost. This might be due to changing your table directly (outside of EF), or due to your recent upgrade, or anything. Look at what error it produces, and do some research, which might lead you to why it's failing.

Comment: Yeah I spent all of yesterday and most of today searching things  up without any success. The only error it says is that the index to drop `doesnt exist or I don't have permissions.` which is true because It doesn't exist.

Comment: Then, you need to look at which index doesn't exist, and try and figure out *why* it came to not exist, or how the migration thinks it does - it uses a snapshot of your current entity model to know what has changed. Have you tried re-scaffolding the migration? Have you tried creating the database fresh, and seeing if that works? That might tell you what's at fault. This is all I can offer, I'm afraid - the rest is up to you. My main point still stands: I think the solution you're trying to come up with (in your question), *might not* be the right way about fixing another problem :)

Comment: Okay thanks Geoff. One last question if you dont mind, What is scaffolding? I saw that in the documentation, but didn't quite understand it.

Comment: Scaffolding is just the term for building the migration up, based on the current model applied to the database. It generates the migration to include the changes required to update the database to match your latest model. Re-scaffolding is basically just re-building the migration. It might iron out any previous erroneous index add/remove operations, it might not. Hope you manage to get to the bottom of this :)

Comment: The scaffold seemed to add a bunch of models to my project, but didn't seem to do what I needed. I'll continue my investigation. Thanks!