# RoleManager.RoleExistsAsync() throws discriminator exception

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-identity

My roleManager is of type `RoleManager<ApplicationRole>` where `ApplicationRole` extends `IdentityRole`. For some reason, when I call `roleManager.RoleExistsAsync(role)`, I get an exception:

> Invalid column name 'Discriminator'.\nInvalid column name
>   'Discriminator'."

I found another post that said this is due to some sort of db inheritance. I'm assuming this is because my ApplicationRole extends IdentityRole, but I'm not exactly sure why.

In startup.cs I also do: `services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>`

ApplicationRole:
`

```
public class ApplicationRole : IdentityRole
    {
        // public virtual ICollection<ApplicationUser> Users { get; } = new List<ApplicationUser>();

        public ApplicationRole(){}
        public ApplicationRole(string roleName) : base(roleName) {}
        public virtual ICollection<IdentityUserRole<string>> Users { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<IdentityRoleClaim<string>> Claims { get; set; }
    }
```

`

ApplicationUser
`

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
    {
        [InverseProperty("User")]
        public virtual Player Player { get; set; }

        public List<ApplicationUserClubs> Clubs { get; set; }
        public int? CustomerProfileId { get; set; }
        /// <summary>
        /// Navigation property for the roles this user belongs to.
        /// </summary>
        public virtual ICollection<IdentityUserRole<string>> Roles { get; } = new List<IdentityUserRole<string>>();

        /// <summary>
        /// Navigation property for the claims this user possesses.
        /// </summary>
        public virtual ICollection<IdentityUserClaim<string>> Claims { get; } = new List<IdentityUserClaim<string>>();

        /// <summary>
        /// Navigation property for this users login accounts.
        /// </summary>
        public virtual ICollection<IdentityUserLogin<string>> Logins { get; } = new List<IdentityUserLogin<string>>();
    }
```

`

Comment: You may have to post some code of your role manager and application role.

Comment: @RonBeyer Thanks Ron, I added code of both the ApplicationRole and ApplicationUser as those were the two things I changed when migrating to .NET 2.0

Answer (score 0):

It turns out, I had to do a migration for this to work. My question from:
[.NET IConfiguration returns null for a property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49783303/net-iconfiguration-returns-null-for-a-property)

and

[Specify only one index with fluent api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49762438/specify-only-one-index-with-fluent-api)

is what lead to this. I still don't know why I get extraneous items from my 2nd question though.